# как при парсинге BS4 получить только родителя

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

```html
<div class="friend_block_content">Kastunaka Double Kill<br>
    <span class="friend_small_text">
        <span class="friend_game_link">Dota 2</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Мне нужно забрать из дерева только никнейм, я попробовал написать код, однако вместе с ником я забираю и игру.
Помогите пожалуйста ограничить поиск по древу так, чтобы брался только родитель и не затрагивались потомки.

`user_names = soup.find_all(class_="friend_block_content")`

Проблема так же заключается в том, что в результате нужен список никнеймов. И просто метод find() тут не пройдет.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, можно воспользоваться методом .text, чтобы получить текст в элементе

Comment: Да, но он так же выведет Dota 2

Comment: Вы для начала попробуйте, а потом пишите ))

Comment: Вы правы, что там нужно запустить цикл for для этого. Я же говорю что таким образом получаю лишнюю информацию. А так как объем не маленький чистить это вручную не хочется, вот и задал вопрос

Comment: Можно попробывать с генератором списков (List Comprehension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вытащить никнеймы с помощью списка дочерних элементов [.contents](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#contents-and-children), взяв первый нужный вам элемент.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

xml_content = """
<div class="friend_block_content">Kastunaka Int Kill<br>
    <span class="friend_small_text">
        <span class="friend_game_link">Dota 2</span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="friend_block_content">Kastunaka Double Kill<br>
    <span class="friend_small_text">
        <span class="friend_game_link">Dota 2</span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="friend_block_content">Kastunaka Float Kill<br>
    <span class="friend_small_text">
        <span class="friend_game_link">Dota 2</span>
    </span>
</div>"""


soup = Soup(xml_content, 'lxml')
user_names = soup.find_all(class_="friend_block_content")
nick_names = [user_name.contents[0] for user_name in user_names]
print(nick_names)

---------------------------------

['Kastunaka Int Kill', 'Kastunaka Double Kill', 'Kastunaka Float Kill']
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что нужно)